# What is this shining in the skull?

Tags: torchlight-2

Walking through the Ossean Wastes, I found the following. [image: shining dragon eye]
What is it? I haven't found the way to interact with it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In all the instances I've seen of this set piece, this item is marked as a "Mysterious Socket" (and it's also not glowing to begin with, if I remember correctly). When you kill the champion level enemy near this area, a "Mysterious Gem" drops. When you place the gem into the socket, the eye begins to glow and 2 medium-sized chests appear from under the sand. Each chest contains some gold, random loot, and one "Basilisk Eye" gem (either a [Yellow](http://torchlight2armory.com/item?i=-4279954864667536730), [Black](http://torchlight2armory.com/item?i=-3837336610101057761), or [Green](http://torchlight2armory.com/item?i=310989121583026353) variant). These gems have unique weapon effects, and can be particularly useful for low-level characters when socketed into armor.

Judging from your screenshot, it looks like you may have already socketed the gem and received the loot.

Comment: So weird. I don't recall doing anything of the sort there, surely not putting a gem in there. I do have a couple of basilisk eyes, so I must have triggered this somehow.

Comment: It is easy to pick up the "Mysterious Gem" without realizing it - it shows up as a quest item and does not go in your inventory.  It is easy to click on the Mysterious Socket unintentionally as well, and as long as you possess the Mysterious Gem it will be used automatically.  If you did that in the middle of a heated battle it is even conceivable that you may have missed the chests coming out of the ground.